# Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256]; in clr

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

How can i use `Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];` but in CLR.
i have `array<System::Byte>^ bytes;` but i have no idea how to give it 256
im out of luck. Would apperice the help, thanks

Comment: O.T.: `Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];`? Shouldn't it be `Byte *bytes = new Byte[256];`?

Comment: Beside of the fact that I don't know anything about CLR, but google is my friend: [How to: Load Unmanaged Resources into a Byte Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-load-unmanaged-resources-into-a-byte-array)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is how to specify the length of the array, correct?

In C++/CLI, arrays are full-fledged objects, not just a block of memory. You create it with `gcnew`, and pass the array length as a constructor parameter.

```
cli::array<Byte>^ bytes = gcnew cli::array<Byte>(256);
```